# Custom Component Error on Save / Edit: Save failed with the following error: Prepared statement needs to be re-prepared

Tags: custom-component, joomla-5.x

I have here a really curious issue in Joomla 5.0.0 on a custom component I'm building right now. In one of the views i cannot save edits on existing elements (create new elements is not an issue at all). Additionally I'm facing this issue only on the PreProd (Shared Hoster Environment with the same config the prod will have).
When trying to save an edited element i get the error

```
Save failed with the following error: Prepared statement needs to be re-prepared
```

I've tried already with PHP 8.2 / 8.1

DB Version on host is:  8.0.35-0ubuntu0.20.04.1

There are no issues when trying to edit & save other views inside the same component to be honest the related view with this issue is the most complex one. But as far as i can see there are no bindings at all.

Here you will find the Branch to this extension:
https://github.com/marcorensch/Joomla_com_Marathon_Manager_2

The view with the issues is the "event" view aswell as the "events" view > you cannot change the publishing status of an event in the events view.

On my Dev Machine it runs great using Joomla 4.4.0 php 8.2 and MySQL 5.7.39

Can someone may direct me into the right direction what went wrong here while saving / updating an existing Event Element? Can I improve my codebase because default Joomla elements and other element types of this extension works well...

thanks in advance.

Edit:
Tested now in my local environment on MySQL 8.0.34 and PHP 8.2 with Joomla 5 > no issue

Sidenote: if you try to install this extension to do a test, AcyMailing Enterprise is required to be installed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey it looks like I've solved the issue now.
I've simply changed in the Joomla Configruation the Database Driver / Type from MySQLi to MySQL and it looks like it's working now...